# What is kinetic mass of photon?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass-energy

Today an unusual thought stroke my mind. A mass moving will some velocity has energy called kinetic energy. Everyone knows that nature loves symmetry so why doesn't moving energy ( photon ) has mass ( maybe kinetic mass )? And if it does have mass ( kinetic ) then what is it?

Comment: Mass equals energy at rest and your expression "kinetic mass" is a self contradiction. A photon's energy tends to zero, because of red shift, when an observer approaches light speed in parallel to it. So photons have zero mass. In practice, the observational upper limit to its mass at present is  $1.07 \times 10^{−27}$ atomic mass units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Einstein's mass-energy equivalence principle, in units where $c=1$, is quite beautiful. It states that

$$ E^2 = m^2 + p^2,$$

which means that the total energy $E$ of an object is the given by the sum of the squares of the rest mass $m$ and the object's translational momentum, $p$. You can easily see for when rest mass $m=0$, you have

$$ E = p. $$

In special relativity, we see here that energy, mass, and momentum are all intimately linked. Even though a photon has no rest mass ($m=0$), it does have an effective mass $E=p$, which is really its energy/momentum (although that doesn't really have a different meaning).

You could call this $E=p$ its kinetic mass, but really it is often called an inertial mass, since it acquires this mass from the fact that it has momentum. This effective mass is why radiation pressure, gravitational lensing of photons, etc. is possible.

Comment: You can define variants of the word "mass" this way, but I don't think it's useful. It looks like you're basically defining "effective mass" or "kinetic mass" to be completely synonymous with energy in general.  That's a useless definition, though, because then we could just say "energy".

Comment: Moreover, the identification of "kinetic mass" with "inertial mass" is simply incorrect, assuming you're using the standard definition of inertial mass.

Comment: I would say that in relativity, objects have energy, momentum, and rest mass, and there's no point in defining tons of variants of mass (effective/kinetic/relativistic/etc. mass) to try to make things more intuitive. It just makes everything more confusing.

Comment: zhutchens1, how is your equation E=p dimensionally consistent?

Comment: @knzhou Not sure if there is a formal definition of kinetic mass, so I was relating the user's use of the term to our general use of inertial mass in the physics community. I appreciate your input, but respectfully disagree: I believe that the concepts of, e.g., inertial mass are pedagogically useful and helpful in illustrating why objects can have an inertia beyond their rest mass, due only to their velocity compared to $c$.

Comment: @DavidWhite In natural units, we define $c=1$ to be dimensionless. In SR, time and space are unified, so they have equivalent units. Both time and distance can be measured in seconds because the speed of light is constant. As a result, velocities have no units (distance/time). Therefore, mass, momentum, and energy have equivalent dimensions (think $m$, $mv$, $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ all have units of kilograms).

Comment: The equation is $E=m²c⁴+p²c²$

Comment: @LoopBack That's the equation in SI units. The equation I presented is in natural units, where $c=1$ and has no units. See my above comment for the logic on this. Note that if $c=1$, your equation collapses to mine.